# Convert a 2D dict with nonnumerical keys to a matrix which supports matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a set of documents labeled by a unique string identifier, and these act as keys to a dictionary, where the values are dicts corresponding to strings which are the words inside the document; the value inside the inner dict is a float. I tried to use the scipy dok_matrix to turn this into a matrix but I am getting an error. Below is my code:

```
 def getMatrix_N(traindocs, N):
     #Just gets N random document vectors and returns it as sparse matrix 
     docIds = random.sample(trainDocs.keys(), k=N)
     matrix = {}
     for docId in docIds:
          matrix[docId] = trainDocs[docId].doc_vec
     return matrix
```

I then tried:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     m1 = getMatrix_N(trainDocs, 10)
     mat1 = dok_matrix(m1)
```

which returns an error:

```
 TypeError: Expected rank <=2 dense array or matrix.
```

So my question was either how to fix this (and also how to do matrix multiplication between two of these types of matrices -- the matrices may span different subspaces) or if you know about any packages that do this.

Comment: The keys for a `dok_matrix` are `(row, col)` tuples, values like `(1,3)`, `(100, 33)`.  The same sort of indices that we use to index elements of a 2d `numpy` array.  Check the `dok_matrix` docs.  In `dok_matrix(D)`, `D` has to be a regular dense 2d array, not a dictionary.

Comment: @hpaulj ay im gonna work on trying to see if i could hash distinct strings to an int to get my code running. Do you know of any dictsxdicts to matrix things out there for now though?